# Trying to upload image with formdata and fetch api in reactnative but when trying to print formdata in php file no image data is there why?

Tags: php, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

In the PHP file, image details are not displaying. but in js file formdata is consoled proper.
How to pass image details to php file using fetch and formdata?

I have run this in macOS.

This is Demo.js file for uploading image in folder and store name in phpmyadmin.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Button, Image, View } from "react-native";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import { ROOT_URL } from "../../get_connection";

export default class Demo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    image: null,
    Image_TAG: ""
  };

  render() {
    let { image } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Button
          title="Pick an image from camera roll"
          onPress={this._pickImage}
        />
        {image && (
          <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPermissionAsync();
  }

  getPermissionAsync = async () => {
    if (Constants.platform.ios) {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
      if (status !== "granted") {
        alert("Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!");
      }
    }
  };

  _pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3]
    });

    console.log(result);
    if (result.cancelled) {
      return;
    }
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.setState({
        image: result.uri
      });
    }

    // ImagePicker saves the taken photo to disk and returns a local URI to it
    let localUri = result.uri;
    let filename = localUri.split("/").pop();

    // Infer the type of the image
    let match = /\.(\w+)$/.exec(filename);
    let type = match ? `image/${match[1]}` : `image`;

    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("photo", {
      image: localUri, // your file path string
      image_tag: filename,
      type
    });
    data.append("hh", "bb");
    console.log(data);
    fetch(`${ROOT_URL}/uploadImage.php`, {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
      },
      method: "POST",
      body: data
    })
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(responseJson => {
        console.log(responseJson);
        alert(responseJson);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };
}


**This is php servlet file.**

<?php 
 // Importing DBConfig.php file.
  include 'DBConfig.php';

  // Creating connection.
  $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

    //$json = file_get_contents('php://input');     
    // $obj = json_decode($json,true);

     // Image uploading folder.
     $target_dir = "uploads";
 print_r($_POST);
 exit;
     // Generating random image name each time so image name will not be same .
     $target_dir = $target_dir . "/" .rand() . "_" . time() . ".jpeg";

     // Receiving image tag sent from application.
     $img_tag = $_POST["photo"]["image_tag"];


    if($image_tag!=""){ 
         // Receiving image sent from Application   
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_dir)){

    // Adding domain name with image random name.
    $target_dir = $domain_name . $target_dir ;

    // Inserting data into MySQL database.
    //mysqli_query("insert into image_upload_table (image_tag, image_path) VALUES('$img_tag' , '$target_dir')");
    $add = mysqli_query($con,"insert into image_upload_table (image_tag, image_path) VALUES('$img_tag' , '$target_dir')");

    if($add){
      echo  json_encode("Image Uploaded Successfully."); // alert msg in react native
    }
    else{
       echo json_encode('check internet connection'); // our query fail         
    }

        }
    }
?>
```

I expect form data with image details but this is what I got.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrNvz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tquuk.png)